# Unable to cancel multiple alarms at once

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, repeat, cancellation

I have a switch in the settings, which is when on will set multiple alarms through alarm manager and if off then will cancel all the alarms being set. both are in different methods, but it is not cancelling any alarms at all. I have checked all the links and understood that if I don't specify all the request codes and just call .cancel it will cancel every alarm (I also tried to keep track of the ids but it can't work in my case). below is the code.

```
 // in on create it is getting the value from settings

if(test==true){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "in MainAct true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setAlarm1();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "in MainAct False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        unsetAlarm();

    }
```

for setting Alarm

```
   public void setAlarm1() { // on click of notification , checking oka? don't be so..

    int columnIndex = 0; // Whichever column we want to fetchh, 0 coz i fetch only time's col so yeahhhh.....
    int secondColumnIndex = 1;
    int keyidColumnIndex = 2;

    handler = new SQLiteDB(getBaseContext());
    handler.open();
    Cursor C = handler.returnData();
    String[] DealTimes = new String[C.getCount()];
    String[] NotificationText = new String[C.getCount()];
    String[] keyIds = new String[C.getCount()];
  //  intent_ids = new int[C.getCount()];


    if (C.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < C.getCount(); i++) {

            //   DealTimes[i] = C.getBlob(columnIndex);
            DealTimes[i] = C.getString(columnIndex);
            NotificationText[i] = C.getString(secondColumnIndex);
            keyIds[i] = C.getString(keyidColumnIndex);

            C.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    C.close();
    handler.close();


    // Converting that string array into an array of time
    /////////---------- WORKED ALHUMDULLIALHHHH <3 <3
    ////           Above wokring coool, next is experiment, and it worked :D <3

    int[] h = new int[C.getCount()];
    int[] m = new int[C.getCount()];
    long[] AllTime = new long[C.getCount()];


    Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
    alertIntent.putExtra("strings", DealTimes);  // sending deal times thoruh string to AlertReceverrr !!!

    for (int i = 0; i < C.getCount(); i++) {


        h[i] = Integer.valueOf(DealTimes[i].split(":")[0]);
        m[i] = Integer.valueOf(DealTimes[i].split(":")[1]);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        int curHr = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h[i]);

        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m[i]);
        calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


        if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }

        alertIntent.putExtra("text", NotificationText[i]);


        AllTime[i] = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        intent_ids[i] = _id; // for keeping track of id, but it won't work coz every time I run the application it will generate new ids and at the time of cancel it will cancel the recent ones not all.

        Log.i("setAlarm", "intent idsss" + intent_ids[i] + "original id = " + _id);  
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        pendingIntent =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,AllTime[i],AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,

                pendingIntent);
                  }

}
```

for cancelling

```
public void unsetAlarm() {

        handler = new SQLiteDB(getBaseContext());
        handler.open();
        Cursor C = handler.returnData();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        Log.i("unsetAlarm", "intent idsss outside loop" + intent_ids );

        for (int i = 0; i < C.getCount(); i++) {
            Log.i("untAlarm", "intent ids seprate loop" + intent_ids[i]);
        }
         pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    try{
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("FAILED TO CANCEL", "cancel failed " + e.getMessage());
    }



    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancelling notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();` as unique id to set or un-set the alarm. Because `System.currentTimeMillis()` will be different after every milliseconds. You should use some unique value according to your project's requirement as  `int _id` this value. Else your are doing good.

Comment: I have updated my code please re-check. and if I remove final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); for request code, then i'll have to provide unique ids my self which is not possible coz I have to so many alarm times coming from database which keeps on changing so I can't hardcode it.

Comment: @shahtajkhalid I am not telling you to hard-code it. You just need to provide unique ids to each alarm you set. May be you can retrieve the unique id based from your db itself.

Comment: Oh I got it. and it Worked :D Thanksss a lot.